# How can I produce a branch cut in a surface plot based made with ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I need to create some surface plots, based on a function that is computationally expensive (a few minutes per point). The function has some branch cuts.

The command `Plot3D` does not work because it just takes too long -- never finishes at any acceptable resolution. I can get enough data points (over a day or three), put them in a matrix, and use `ListPlot3D` to produce a plot. But I don't see how to make *Mathematica* recognize the branch cut and not connect the two sides at the discontinuity.

Comment: Have you considered using `RegionFunction` to exclude a narrow strip around the discontinuity?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting idea. In my case, the branch cuts are not in any analytic form, so calculating them would be nontrivial. I did just think of another solution, making use of the fact that in my case, the branch cuts are closed loops. I could separate the data points "by hand" (values are greater or less than such and such) into two (or, in my case, three) separate matrices, and plot them with `ListPlot3D` on the same figure. Ad hoc, not elegant, and each figure would take some user effort, but I think doable. There should be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

One option is simply to create the `ListPlot3D` and post-process it to remove polygons which are too steep.

```
data = With[{g := GaussianFilter[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 50}], 25]}, ArcTan[g, g]];
plot = ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None] // Normal;
toosteep[Polygon[pts_, ___]] := Module[{z = pts[[All, 3]]}, Max[z] - Min[z] > 1]
DeleteCases[plot, _Polygon?toosteep, -1]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use a `RegionFunction` to exclude regions where the function gradient is high. Here I use a bit of image processing to locate the branch cuts:

```
exclude = Image[data] ~GradientFilter~ 1 ~Binarize~ 1.5 ~Dilation~ 1
```

[image]

```
regionfunc = ListInterpolation[ImageData@exclude, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, regionfunc[y, x] < 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if I can use the techniques in this http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/758/ function to improve the accuracy of the location of the branch cuts (which in my case are smooth curves). (Apologies for not doing this myself and writing it here. I'm not that proficient in Mathematica. It will take me a few days to figure it out.)

Comment: @RichardTasgal, you could, but this of course increases the number of evaluations of your expensive function as you iteratively refine the location of the cuts. This is why `Plot3D` takes so long - it is increasing the sampling density near the discontinuity.

Comment: One other thing, if you are "not that proficient" in *Mathematica* it may be that your expensive function is coded inefficiently. What sort of computations are involved?

Comment: The function is as follows: I have a 6th-order polynomial equation where the coefficients depend on a few variables, a0(k,a,b)+a1(k,a,b)y+a2(k,a,b)y^2+a3(k,a,b)y^3+a4(k,a,b)y^4+a5(k,a,b)y^5+a6(k,a,b)y^6=0. The functions a_j(k,a,b) take a few tens of lines to define---involving functions of functions and a determinant---but they are algebraic expressions. Then I find the location k of the largest imaginary root of the 6 solutions y_j (`Max`,`Imag`,`NSolve`) over all k (`NMaximize`), holding a,b constant. I plot this over a,b.  Compile doesn't help the speed. Maybe I'm missing a subtlety.

Comment: @RichardTasgal, it sounds like its just a really big calculation. I'd be happy to have a look if you can post a link to the notebook, but it may be that several minutes per point is as fast as it gets.

Comment: I don't know if it's OK for me to post the formulas before the article is published. I really do appreciate the assistance. The thing that I was wondering about especially is compiling when a user-defined function calls another user-defined function. Should the lower-level and higher-level user-defined functions all be compiled separately, or is there perhaps another subtlety?

Comment: @RichardTasgal, I fully understand about sharing details of the work before it is published! There *are* subtleties with calling user-defined functions from within compiled code. In particular, you usually want to avoid callbacks to the main evaluator. I suggest you read the tutorial [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html), especially the sections on the **InlineCompiledFunctions** and **InlineExternalDefinitions** options.

Comment: Following-up. It turns out that my biggest problem was with `NMaximize`, and the fact that the function it was operating on (described above) was "pathological" enough to make `NMaximize` (with all the available Method options; `FindMaximum`, too) choke every now and then (unpredictably!), and take forever, and give bad results. The issue was that the function `NMaximize` operates on is identically zero for some regions. (Where the function is non-zero, it is smooth, finite, and well-behaved.) I wrote my own function to replace `NMaximize`, and things worked.